# PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer doesn't working with ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I'm trying to use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to load some variables located in property files, but it is not working.
Some sites on internet suggested that the problem happens when spring aop isn't in the classpath, but I ensured the aop framework is on my project. Here is my springContext.xml:

```
    <!-- Register all placeholder locations -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" >
    <property name="order" value="0" />
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>file:/mypath/file.properties</value>             
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Register all placeholder locations -->
<password-decrypter order="10" id="passwordConfigurer">
<decrypter algorithm="PBEWithSHAAnd128BitRC4" key="${Encryption.key}" />
    <decryption-entries>
        <decryption-entry bean-ref="ds" properties="password" />
    </decryption-entries>
</password-decrypter>
```

And here is the error throwing:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'password-decrypter'.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:417)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3182)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1927)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:705)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:400)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2755)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:235)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:351)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:280)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:131)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:147)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:173)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:112)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:79)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:101)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:389)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:324)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:91)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:75)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:65)
```

Do I need to do something different when running the program outside a container to use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer with ClassPathXmlApplicationContext?

Comment: What are your XML schema header definitions? What are the schemas configured for the XML? The exception is complaining about parsing XML configuration of Spring beans.

Comment: Is the password-decrypter tag for a bean of yours? I didn't find anything like that on Spring and its submodules.

Comment: If you are using NetBeans: right click on xml code editor > Validate XML.

Comment: @nobeh you are right... I need a .jar that provide informationa about the "decrypt xsd" tag

Comment: I found a jar with the correct xsd file, but running the unit tests they are throwing the same error. How can I configure to spring found the xsd files of the classpath?

Comment: What's the library that you're using? Jasypt?

Comment: Yes, I solved the problem. It's occurrying with some custom libs, so, I need to use exclusion tag of maven to don't use spring and use the Libs provided by my customer. Without exclusion tag the classpath was loading something that broke all the solution. It's not worthile to write more details here because the problem is relationed with a private custom framework based on spring framework. But your answer was right @nobeh. Loading the XSD was the root error. Now that it's configured, it,s loading.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative approach to this. you can try it as mentioned below.

Instead of defining the the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in applicationContext.xml , use the below code to define it in ServletContextListener

```
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    ResourceLoader resourceLoader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
    Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:localDB.properties");

    configurer.setLocation(resource);
    configurer.postProcessBeanFactory(beanFactory);
```

Here *beanFactory* is an *XmlBeanFactory* created using ClassPathResource.

The property file localDB.properties can contain the appropriated values and they can be used in the applicationContext.xml as *${Encryption.key}*,  Here Encryption.key is one of the key from the properties file